# Remove every user from a discord role

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

is there a way to delete all users from certain groups in a limit-saving way?
The way to delete every user one by one from a group seems very time consuming to me.

There are both possibilities, via a bot (Discord.js) that is already on the server or the Discord API.

Comment: You can delete the role. This doesn't spam the API, and is easy to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is to just delete the role. The [Role.delete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Role?scrollTo=delete) method returns the Role after it has been deleted. You can just pass that exact return value back into `guild.roles.create` to clone the options from the previous role, in case you need to keep the properties of the Role but do not want the members anymore.

Ex:

```
declare const client: Client<true>
const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(`some-guild-id`)
const role = await guild.roles.fetch(`deleting-role-id`)
if (role) {
  const deleted = await role.delete()
  const recreated = await guild.roles.create(deleted)
}
```

This would be a pretty clean solution.

Comment: I have also thought about this possibility, the issue is that thus the settings of the group in the channels on each Discord server must be set again. Since this procedure takes place every 3 months, we would like to spare the server owners this.

Comment: You could grab all of the PermissionOverwrites that apply to the old Role and map those over to the re-created Role relatively easily. [Here's a quick snippet (you'll have to remove any Typescript annotations if your Project is JS, but I reckon that's not too much to ask).](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-elion-9y3otc?file=/src/index.ts)

Comment: You'd likely also want to account for Permission Overwrites that can be found elsewhere -- [I'd sift through this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/search?query=PermissionOverwrites), I know Application Commands definitely have Overwrites that you might want to keep track of. Not sure what else might.

Comment: this will help thanks for the suggestion!